# Does sqlite add any metadata information with select query result?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I've an API accessing my sqlite database to perform a select query. My doubt is that ,

1. Does sqlite leave any information about the database tables in the select query result ?
2. Does it leave any other information about database schema

API performs a select query in the database

Comment: You can get information about the result set with [GetSchemaTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatareader.getschematable?view=netcore-3.1), but that is not the same as table schema. Consider the fact that you can SELECT 'foo', which is not from a table at all. Or, do joins on multiple tables.

Comment: @Crowcoder would the select query return metadata information like name of the database or what time the query is executed ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on your question tags, it looks like you are using the ADO.NET provider for Sqlite. So, no you do not get that kind of information. I don't know if there is any way to obtain that. MS SQL Server has hooks that allow profiling but that information still does not surface in ADO.NET. I don't know what Sqlite's profiling capabilities, if any, are.